# Display product_uom_qty as integer instead of float

Tags: view, odoo, odoo-10

I need to display the field **product_uom_qty** under sale.order.line (of Sale order) and **quantity** under account.invoice.line (of an invoice) as an integer instead of the current floating point.

How can I do it?

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are asking for Odoo 10:

1. Go to `Settings` in `Debug` mode.
2. Under the `Technical > Database Structure > Decimal Accuracy` click the menu.
3. Find `Product Unit of Measure` and edit it to `0` digits.

This will change whenever `product_uom_qty` is accessed with `Decimal Accuracy` precision, not just Sales Orders.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in the model, you can set digits like this.

```
fields.float('Quantity', digits=(x,y))
```

If you want to do it in the view, you can set digits like this.

```
<field digits="(x,y)" name="product_uom_quantity"/>
```

where `x` is the digits before the decimal point, and `y` is the digits after the decimal point. So, if you set `y` to 0 it will have no decimal point seemingly an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the widget attribute to `integer`.

***Example:***

```
<field name="product_uom_qty" widget="integer"/>
```