# Change customer_lead field type

Tags: odoo-15

On the sale order report in Odoo, I'm displaying the `customer_lead` field. This field is defined as float and I'd like to change it to Int just because I need a number of days (2, 4, 5, etc)

[image]

I tried to add this code inside my python file but it's not changing it to Int

```
from odoo import fields, models, api


class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.form'

customer_lead = fields.Int(string='Cust. Lead.')
```

How can the default field type be changed?

Comment: Try to use the integer widget in the view definition (`<field name="customer_lead" widget="integer"/>`), check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73864157/display-product-uom-qty-as-integer-instead-of-float/73865171#73865171)

Comment: Also, just in case, it's not fields.Int(), it's fields.Integer() :)

Comment: I need to show it as integer not only in form but on print report also. Using widget="integer" didn't change it to integer (not even in form view) - strange. 

At the moment I'm using custom char field for this, but it would be nice to know how can we change default field types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the field type from `Float` to `Integer`, you will lose the field values.

Odoo defined the `widget` attribute to customize the field's behavior so you can use the integer widget in the view definition

```
<field name="customer_lead" widget="integer"/>
```

To automatically display the integer part of the float value

You can also use the same in the QWEB report, just specify the widget you want to use in the field [options](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/frontend/qweb.html#smart-records-fields-formatting):

```
<field name="customer_lead" t-options="{'widget': 'integer'}"/>
```

*Note that Odoo uses the integer widget on the [available_threshold](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/website_sale_stock/models/product_template.py#L12) field in the [form view](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/website_sale_stock/views/product_template_views.xml#L19)*